# Can't get into bios

Tags: linux, boot, solus

I installed solus os and accidently didn't include boot menu .Os doesn't boot and can't get into the bios either.Is that fixable?
Plz,help.My device is Dell Inspiron 5567

Comment: Getting into the BIOS configuration is independent of the OS. Try  pressing F2, "delete" and F12 one after the other over and over after powering on. Check the hardware user manual from the manufacturer web site as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124211/dell-bios-updates

To access the BIOS or System Setup on Dell computers:

1. Press the **F2** key several times at the Dell logo screen during startup.
2. Or, press the **F12** key several times at the Dell logo screen during startup, and select BIOS Setup or System Setup from the menu.